# Does rostopic echo no longer work for arrays?

Tags: ros-groovy, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently switched to groovy and rostopic doesn't seem to be able to handle arrays anymore.  Does anyone know why?

Example for me, from a simple topic with a list of doubles:
`rostopic echo /robot/joint_states/position[1]`

Results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/ros/groovy/bin/rostopic", line 35, in <module>
    rostopic.rostopicmain()   File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rostopic/__init__.py", line 1666, in rostopicmain
    _rostopic_cmd_echo(argv)   File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rostopic/__init__.py", line 1026, in _rostopic_cmd_echo
    _rostopic_echo(topic, callback_echo, bag_file=options.bag)   File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rostopic/__init__.py", line 692, in _rostopic_echo
    index = submsg_class.__slots__.index(field) ValueError: 'position[1]' is not in list`
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72940/does-rostopic-echo-no-longer-work-for-arrays?/) by [mattadc](https://answers.ros.org/users/5947/mattadc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-08-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-08-15**:
Are you sure that that topic is correct? Can you update this question with the results of rostopic info /robot/joint_states ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like a regression of https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/242

It is fixed in https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/commit/2af3d693645f084086ef0a5c50f9b666ea0fc1fd and will be available with the next ros_comm release (1.9.48).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mattadc](https://answers.ros.org/users/5947/mattadc/) on 2013-08-16**:
Yes, this fixed the problem.  Thank!